# How to set Icons into ListItems dynamically?

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

I have a ListView whose list item comes from a 'String' from Shared Preference. Now I have to set two icons "success" and "failed" identifying those keywords "successful" and "failed" from string. But while setting it is either setting "success" icons to all listitems or "failed" icons to all reason because string contains both. Any idea how can i identify each list items and set icons to them ? Below is my code :

Class where I am retrieving "oldlistitems" and "newlistitems" strings from Shared Preference and trying to set icons to listitems

```
public class EntryAdapterLog extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;
    private LayoutInflater vi;

    public EntryAdapterLog(Context context,ArrayList<Item> items) {
        super(context,0, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        final Item i = items.get(position);
        if (i != null) {
            if(i.isSection()){
                SectionItem si = (SectionItem)i;
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);

                v.setOnClickListener(null);
                v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
                v.setLongClickable(false);

                final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
                sectionView.setText(si.getTitle());
            }else{

                String oldlistitems = LogListView.first;
                String newlistitems = LogListView.title;
                Log.d("LOG", "ABCD : " + oldlistitems);
                Log.d("LOG", "DEFG : " + newlistitems);

                EntryItem ei = (EntryItem)i;
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_entry_log, null);
                final TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);
                final TextView subtitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_summary);
                final ImageView imageicon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_drawable);

                if(title != null) {
                    title.setText(ei.title);
                }
                if(subtitle != null){
                    subtitle.setText(ei.subtitle);
                }
                //HERE IS PROCESS OF SETTING ICONS
                if ((oldlistitems !=null && oldlistitems.contentEquals("Sync Successful")) || (newlistitems != null && newlistitems.contentEquals("Sync Successful"))){
                    imageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
                }
                else {
                    imageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
                }

            }
        }
        return v;
    }

}
```

Class where i am setting shared preference

```
public class LogListView extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    static String newString;
    private static EntryAdapterLog adapter;
    int clickCounter = 0;
    static ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    static SharedPreferences preferences = null;
    private static Context context = null;
    static StringTokenizer tokens;
    static String first;
    private static String second;
    private JSONArray jsonarry = null;
    static String saveitems;
    private JSONObject jsonobject = null;
    private String subtitle;
    static String title;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        context = this;
        adapter = new EntryAdapterLog(this, items);
        // items.add(new SectionItem("Log Report"));
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        if (adapter.getCount() != 0) {
            // Do nothing Adapter has value
        } else {
            retreiveItems();
        }

    }

    // Method which will handle dynamic insertion
    public static void addItems() {

        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("LOG",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        newString = preferences.getString("log", "");

        tokens = new StringTokenizer(newString, ",");
        first = tokens.nextToken();
        second = tokens.nextToken();

        items.add(new EntryItem(first, second));

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    // Method which will handle dynamic insertion ends

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        saveItems();
    }

    // Save ListItems if restarted
    protected static void saveItems() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefName",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("myList", new Gson().toJson(items).toString());
        editor.apply();
        Log.d("LOG", "Saved Items : " + items);
    }
    // Save ListItems if restarted ends

    // Retrieve ListItems if restarted
    protected void retreiveItems() {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("prefName",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        saveitems = preferences.getString("myList", "");
        Log.d("LOG", "Retreived Items : " + saveitems);

        try {
            jsonarry = new JSONArray(saveitems);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (jsonarry == null || jsonarry.length() == 0) {
            return;                                                                        //This checks before setting adapter onCreate if adapter is null
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarry.length(); i++) {

            try {
                jsonobject = jsonarry.getJSONObject(i);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // get all values here from JSONObject
            title = jsonobject.optString("title");
            subtitle = jsonobject.optString("subtitle");

            items.add(new EntryItem(title, subtitle));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }
    // Retrieve ListItems if restarted ends

    // Counter for amount of period of time before flusing adapter
    protected void flushList(){

    }
    // Counter for amount of period of time before flusing adapter ends

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        if (!items.get(position).isSection()) {
            items.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        if (position == 9) {

        }

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }




}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to update the icon for *each* item, based on if `sync successful` or `sync failed` for that item.

You should do something like this (update your code accordingly):

```
//HERE IS PROCESS OF SETTING ICONS
if ((ei.title.contains("Sync Successful")) {
    imageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
}
else {
    imageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Amulya...That really worked. How dumb of me...I was getting string value from shared prefs and trying to identify from it...God bless ya

Answer (score 0):

First of all your adapter will laggy when you will have big number of list items, you should use ViewHolder pattern as is described [HERE](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)

Second, it will be better to get all the data from sharedPreferences and store them in an ArrayList and give that list to adapter, Reading and Writing to SharedPreferences is an expansive operation.
Also to handle if the sync is success or fail use a boolean in your Item object, and in the adapter just chec that boolean and like this change the drawable of the list item.

Comment: Thanks @Eddy, But that would have been costly thing for me to do coz i would have to make lot of changes

Comment: This will make your life easier later, when you will add some more stuff that you will like to display, or event add another check option to display success or fail,by the way, checking a string.equalsignoreccase or contains it's also very heavy operation

Comment: I agree, sooner or later i will have to make that changes... :(

Comment: Yes, and it is better to do them from the beginning and just to add options to the code and not rewrite it :)